# Is E-texteditor's "open company" and open source model really open?

Tags: open-source

E-Texteditor recently [announced](http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2009/opencompany) going open-source with their open company model. However after reading through I am not sure if this model is really open.

The way I understand is that they open up the source and contributors, depending on how much the contribute get badges (like at stackoverflow) and are compensated accordingly from the company's revenue stream. Here are the steps:

> 1st step: Releasing the source
>
> The source will be made a available,
>   so that users can study and modify the
>   application for their own needs. If
>   they want to contribute their changes
>   back, they can submit them for review.
>   To discourage piracy, a tiny but
>   essential core (also containing the
>   licensing code), will be kept private
>   (at least until users reach a certain
>   rating). This will gradually be
>   followed by a similar opening of the
>   rest of the company (web site,
>   documentation, bug tracking, etc..)
>
> 2nd step: Building the Trust Metric
>
> The basic infrastructure will be set
>   up so that participants can start
>   rating each other. The algorithms and
>   code will be released as open source,
>   so that they can be studied and
>   discussed (and used by others). It
>   will probably need quite some time and
>   tweaking before we reach a fair
>   balance.
>
> 3rd step: Compensating Participants
>
> All income in the company (minus
>   operating expenses), will be passed
>   through the trust metric and
>   distributed to participants.

The company still keeps some bits private to retain control and that doesn't make it truly open. How is that any different from hiring developers and compensating them with stock options and merit-based bonuses?

EDIT: David Brown points out the [developer response](http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2009/releasing-the-source)

> While the addition of the extra clause
>   means that the license can no longer be
>   termed an Open Source License, it is
>   ideal for the open company. It is
>   essentially an issue of mutual respect.
>   If I fully respect your ownership, you
>   will in return respect my right to make
>   a living.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is that any different from hiring developers and compensating them with stock options and merit-based bonuses?

I'd say the difference is that **anyone** can be an developer.

> The company still keeps some bits private to retain control and that doesn't make it truly open.

Google Chrome is the same way. The actual open source part of it is a project called Chromium. Google takes contributions to the Chromium project, integrates it with the proprietary bits of Chrome, and releases it to the public.

It looks perfectly fine to me as an open source project. It's just not the traditional way of doing things.

**EDIT:** It appears the E developer has [answered your question](http://e-texteditor.com/blog/2009/releasing-the-source):

> While the addition of the extra clause means that the license can no longer be termed an Open Source License, it is ideal for the open company. It is essentially an issue of mutual respect. If I fully respect your ownership, you will in return respect my right to make a living.

Comment: the difference is that chromium is fully functional, while they're keeping "a tiny but essential core"

Comment: It's fully functional, yes, but Google then takes it and adds thing like GoogleUpdater, which is not open source. So, essentially, it's not entirely open source. Besides, as the article states, the core will be available to those with a high contribution rating.

Comment: The core is available to them for development purposes only much like you trust key developers with the code in your company. GoogleUpdater is not the core, quite the opposite in fact. The engine is what matters most.

Comment: It boils down to personal opinion, really. Frankly, I'm not one to stick to the OSI definition. An open source project is anything that I can contribute to and learn from. If they want to keep the licensing to themselves, that's perfectly OK with me.

Answer (score 3):

If the "essential core" prevent us from forking the project or creating a mac port, it's not really open source.